# Program does not enter the while loop

Tags: c, struct, text-files, file-handling, binaryfiles

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Employee {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float salary;
};

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char filename[] = "employee.txt";
    int dataFound = 0;
    int recordno = 0;

    // Step 1: Open the file in read and write mode
    file = fopen(filename, "r+");

    // Step 2: Check if the file opened successfully
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file %s for reading and writing.\n", filename);
        return 1;  // Exit with an error code
    }
    char name[15];
    // Step 3: Get the name of the employee to be updated
    printf("Enter the name of the employee to be updated: ");
    gets(name);

    // Step 4: Search for the employee with the specified name
    struct Employee emp;

    while (fread(&emp, sizeof(emp), 1, file) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(emp.name, name) == 0) {\
            dataFound = 1;
            // Employee found, update the details
            printf("Enter the new details for employee %d:\n", emp.id);
            printf("Id: ");
            scanf("%d", &emp.id);
            printf("Salary: ");
            scanf("%f", &emp.salary);

            // Move the file pointer to the beginning of the current record
            fseek(file, sizeof(struct Employee), SEEK_CUR);

            // Write the updated details to the file
            if (fwrite(&emp, sizeof(struct Employee), 1, file) == 1) {
                printf("Employee details updated successfully.\n");
            }
            recordno++;
        }
    }
    if (dataFound == 0) {
        printf("\nData not found\n");
    }

    // Step 5: Close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to update data that is stored in a txt file. I stored the data using structure.
When I reach step 4 the program enters the while loop but the if statement inside the while loop does not return true. (I checked it using `if` `else`) Can anyone help me out?

This is how the data is stored in the **employee.txt** file:

```
Id : 1 
Name : aayush
Salary : 4000 
Id : 2 
Name : aashish
Salary : 3000
```

Comment: _"the program does not seem..."_: that's a meaningless statement. Either it does enter the while loop or it doesn't. Did you check this (using a debugger or adding some printfs)? Maybe employee_data.txt does not contain what you think it does. How did you create this file?

Comment: I just did and realized it does enter the while loop . But the if statement inside the while loop returns false . How do I solve that?

Comment: @AayushPandey you need to correct the question first.  Correction in comments only do not cut it.  The question is unanswerable as is.

Comment: It's been ages since I've used std file functions, but I *think* you cannot read and write file at the same time without truncating on write. It would be better to read file completely and then rewrite it at once, or write to another file and then rename to overwrite original file.

Comment: Note that `char name[15]; gets(name);` will cause problems, if it doesn't already.

Comment: Clearly though `strcmp(emp.name, name) == 0` is false. That is all that can be said, since we do not know what your file contains or what input was received.  `gets()` is fundamentally dangerous and should not be used.   Your structure has a name array length of 40, but your input is limited to 15.

Comment: @Clifford what can i use to take the name as an input then?

Comment: Is that the actual contents of your file or is it just your debug print of the file contents? If it's actually that multi-line text format then you can't read that using fread, which reads binary data into a struct. (Actually, it looks like your printf/scanf interaction with the running program so maybe ok)

Comment: [Alternatives to using `gets` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/694733)

Comment: You are reading a _text_ file into a _binary_ structure.  That will not work.  You will have to deserialize the text and assign the struct members individually with appropriate conversions where necessary.  `fscanf` perhaps?

Comment: You use `fread` for reading lines in a text file. This is fundamentally wrong as `fread` reads raw bytes. You need to read the lines of the file line by line (possibly using `fgets`), parse them and construct the struct from that.

Comment: _"what can i use to take the name as an input then?"_ `fgets()`.  A modern toolchain or library should either exclude gets() or at least issue a warning.  What are you using? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets for example, or any other up to date documentation.

Comment: @Clifford so i tried reading the txt file using fscanf but it only reads the first data ie the first three lines of the employee.txt file . How can i make it read all data ?

Comment: `fscanf(file, " ID : %d Name : %s Salary : %f", &empid, emp.name, &emp.salary)`. Do that in a loop.

Comment: @AayushPandey that is a different quesrion and this is not a discussion forum.  Do not post questions in comments, post a new question with the new wrong code, or wait for someone to answer this one with a solution.

Comment: The title to this question remains incorrect, and you have to read right to the end before discovering that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems

- If the text file **employee.txt** indeed has the posted contents, you cannot load a record with `fread`, you would need to read and parse the contents to extract the record fields according to the syntax and you couldn't update it in place as seems to be the goal of your program because the updated `id` and/or the `salary` could use a different number of characters, corrupting the text file. The employee file must be in binary format with fixed size records for this program and you must open it in binary mode with `"rb"`.
- The reason the `if` test is always false is `emp.name` read via `fread(&emp, ...)` is not the employee name, nor is it a null terminated C string, given the contents of the file, `emp.name` should contain `" 1\nName : aayush\nSalary : 4000\nId : 2\nName : aashi"` without a null terminator (bytes 5 to 54 of the file).
- `gets()` must not be used.  This function cannot test for buffer overflow so it cannot be used safely for user supplied contents. It has been removed from recent versions of the C Standard. Use `fgets()` to read a line and strip the newline.
- the array `name` into which you read the name is too short: 15 bytes, whereas the `name` field of the `Employee` structure has 50 bytes, allowing for names up to 49 characters.
- You seek forward when you have a match instead of seeking backward.
- you must use `fseek` again after writing to the file to allow switching back to reading from it.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Employee {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float salary;
};

int main() {
    char filename[] = "employee.txt";
    int dataFound = 0;
    int recordno = 0;

    // Step 1: Open the file in read and write mode
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb+");

    // Step 2: Check if the file opened successfully
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file %s for reading and writing.\n", filename);
        return 1;  // Exit with an error code
    }
    char name[80];
    // Step 3: Get the name of the employee to be updated
    printf("Enter the name of the employee to be updated: ");
    if (!fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
        printf("missing name\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // strip the newline if any
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';

    // Step 4: Search for the employee with the specified name
    struct Employee emp;

    while (fread(&emp, sizeof(emp), 1, file) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(emp.name, name) == 0) {
            dataFound = 1;
            // Employee found, update the details
            printf("Enter the new details for employee %d:\n", emp.id);
            printf("Id: ");
            scanf("%d", &emp.id);
            printf("Salary: ");
            scanf("%f", &emp.salary);

            // Move the file pointer to the beginning of the current record
            fseek(file, -sizeof(struct Employee), SEEK_CUR);

            // Write the updated details to the file
            if (fwrite(&emp, sizeof(struct Employee), 1, file) == 1) {
                printf("Employee details updated successfully.\n");
            } else {
                printf("write error\n");
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }

            // seek to the current position before reading from the file
            fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_CUR);

            recordno++;
        }
    }
    if (dataFound == 0) {
        printf("\nData not found\n");
    }

    // Step 5: Close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to read a struct Employee but your data isn't in a good format, you need to read the data in the same way where they are written, try to write your struct and you will see that the fill contain strange character it's because we write each bytes of your struct one per one, for exemple a int is 4 bytes and a char is 1 bytes so a int can by write in 4 character.

Use this 2 functions to test how it works :

```
// write to file
int main(void) {
    struct Employee emp;
    emp.id = 1;
    strcpy(emp.name, "John");
    emp.salary = 10000.0;

    FILE *file = fopen("employee.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file employee.txt.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fwrite(&emp, sizeof(struct Employee), 1, file) == 1) {
        printf("Employee details written successfully.\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}

// read from file
int main(void) {
    struct Employee emp;

    FILE *file = fopen("employee.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file employee.txt.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fread(&emp, sizeof(struct Employee), 1, file) == 1) {
        printf("Id: %d\n", emp.id);
        printf("Name: %s\n", emp.name);
        printf("Salary: %.2f\n", emp.salary);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```